# Rails - :date and :time columns show nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, date

I am new to rails, and I have moved a front-end project to the rails environment. I have set up a form with start_date, end_date and start_time columns. start_date and end_date have the column type :date and start_time has the column type :time. I am using a date picker to select the dates and time picker to select the time. The format in which I am receiving both the date and time is:

```
Wed Jan 11 2017 13:31:14 GMT+0530
```

I have formatted the output using moment js to show a more comprehensible date and time format to the user.

```
moment().format('LL'); //January 23,2017
moment().format('LTS'); //1:17:54 PM
```

On submitting the form, the date and time columns are nil.

I have read that I should use Date.parse() and Time.parse() or strftime to convert the dates.

I have two questions:
1. Where should I put the code for the conversion? By intuition, I think it should either be in the controller, or maybe in the view, while taking the input itself.
2. What is the format the :date and :time column accept?

I have sqlite 3 as the database for ActiveRecord and I am using Rails 5.0.1.

home.new.html.erb (form fields for the three column type):

```
 <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field :start_date,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="home_start_date" id="start-date-label">Enter start date</label>
          </div>


          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field :end_date,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="home_end_date" id="end-date-label">Enter end date</label>
          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field :start_time,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="home_start_time" id="start-time-label">Enter time</label>
          </div>
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @campaigns = Home.all
  end

  def new
    @home = Home.new
  end

  def show
    @campaign = Home.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    home_params = params.require(:home).permit(:campaign_name,:phone_number_receiver,:start_date,:end_date,:start_time,:sms_msg)
    @home = Home.new(home_params)
    @home.save
  end
end
```

Link to github : https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/sms-scheduler

Answer (score 2):

You should process the data in the controller - or if there is a lot of data processing to be done, or the processing rules are complicated: have the controller hand the processing to a dedicated data processing object.

I'd suggest modifying your controller code like this:

```
def create  
  @home = Home.create(home_params)
end

private

def home_params
  home_params = params.require(:home).permit(
    :campaign_name, :phone_number_receiver, :start_date, :end_date,    
    :start_time, :sms_msg
  ).tap do |attr|
    attr[:start_date] = Date.parse(attr[:start_date])
    attr[:end_date] = Date.parse(attr[:end_date])
    attr[:start_time] = Time.parse(attr[:start_time])
  end
end
```

[`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) allows you to step into the `params` hash as it is being processed via `require`, and modify it's content.

If the processing was complicated, you could do something like:

```
def home_params
  home_params = params.require(:home).permit(
    :campaign_name, :phone_number_receiver, :start_date, :end_date,    
    :start_time, :sms_msg
  ).tap do |attr|
    ParamsProcessor.modify attr
  end
end
```

Where `ParamsProcessor` is an object you create to handle the processing. For example:

```
module ParamsProcessor
  def self.modify(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value| 
      hash[key] = Date.parse(value) if /_date$/ =~ key && value.present?
      hash[key] = Time.parse(value) if /_time$/ =~ key && value.present?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am new to rails, could you please provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: If you post your controller code, I can suggest how it should be modified.

Comment: I tried out the first code, it is throwing an ArgumentError in HomeController#create   invalid date. Do i need to explicitly specify the date's format?

Comment: Try it at the console. You should be able to see the data passed in, in the logs (for example, `log/development.log`) just above where the error is shown. At the app root, open a console via `rails console` and try entering `Date.parse <string>` where `<string>` is the date string passed in. You could also try `Time.parse`

Comment: Oh! and I'll update my answer to include handling `start_time` which I missed before.

Comment: I did try it on the console - it's throwing an error there too. Does Date.parse convert formats as the one I specified?  Because when i passed in other formats, it did parse them

Comment: Which one is it failing on?

Comment: Both time and date. Date.parse() and Time.parse can't directly parse the [Wed Jan 11 2017 13:31:14 GMT+0530] type format

Comment: ` [Wed Jan 11 2017 13:31:14 GMT+0530]` I can parse that date on my system. Why are there square brackets around the date - is that date within an array? Also what is the error you get?

Comment: I added the square brackets to group the format in the comment, nothing else. Still, not able to parse the dates. Any other way to do this?

Comment: from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console' from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'